# Display CPT ordered by Custom Field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I suspect this is easy, but I seem to be getting confused I think.

Basically I have a Custom Post Type, and Advanced Custom Fields for the content of each.

I need to now loop through one of the Custom Fields (resource_type), and display each post that has ticked that field, displaying them under a heading.

So it would display like:

**resource_type 1**   (Custom Field)

- Resource 1   (Post that has ticked resource_type 1 ACF)
- Resource 2   (Post that has ticked resource_type 1 ACF)
- Resource 3   (Post that has ticked resource_type 1 ACF)

**resource_type 2**    (Custom Field)

- Resource 4    (Post that has ticked resource_type 2 ACF)
- Resource 5    (Post that has ticked resource_type 2 ACF)

I've searched around but can't see anything specifically for this.

this is what I have so far:

```
$cat = get_field('resource_type'); 
    foreach ($cat as $catVal) {
        echo '<h2 style="color: #8D8B8D;">'.$catVal.'</h2><ul>';
        $postArg = array('post_type'=>'resources',
          'search_filter_id' => '13180'
          );

        $getPost = new wp_query($postArg);
        global $post;
          while ( $getPost->have_posts()):$getPost->the_post(); ?>
              <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php 
the_title(); ?></a></li>
          <?php endwhile; 
        echo '</ul>';
    }
```

Comment: Since you're using this `resource_type` to group posts I'd suggest you to use a **custom taxonomy** for this instead. This way it'd be easier to query your `resources` posts for each term.

Comment: Also, I'd be great to know what type of custom field is `resource_type` right now and how many different values has it?